# azure pipeline pytest-cov coverage results not displaying properly an throwing a warning

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a azure pipeline build that runs the following command.

```
pytest tests --junitxml=junit/test-results.xml --cov --cov-report=xml --cov-report=html
```

I know this generates the correct coverage report as azure produces it as an artifact which i can download. The problem is that azure seems to have an issue with the coverage report. i get the following warnings:

```
##[warning]Invalid results file. Make sure the result format of the file '/home/vsts/work/1/s/test-cov.xml' matches 'JUnit' test results format.

##[warning]No code coverage results were found to publish.
```

In the code coverage tab after the pipeline has finished the html output is there but is is incorrectly displayed.

How do i fix this?